# Worst case complexity of generating numbers to equal a set of numbers

Tags: java, algorithm

Here is my code below; I suck at analyzing recursive functions; I think it's O(2^n); what do you guys think? (I know you can write it better, my question is about the run time OF THE CODE BELOW).

```
static int ans = 0;
  public static void ablehelper(int a, int b, int c, int d){
      if(a != c && (b + a) > c){
          return;
      }
      if(b != d && (b + a) > d){
          return;
      }
      if(a == c && b == d){
          ans = 1;
          return;
      }
      ablehelper(a + b, b, c, d);
      ablehelper(a, b + a, c, d);

  }
  public static String able(int a, int  b, int c, int d){
      ablehelper(a, b, c, d);
      if(ans == 1){
          return "Able to generate";
      }else{
          return "Not table to generate";
      }
  }
```

Comment: Consider posting it at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @AlexandreSantos I'm willing to bet they'll move it back here if posted there - they don't deal with actual code AFAIK.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is algorithmic analysis, not a code problem per se, and should be on CS (or possibly Programmers).

Comment: **Why** do you think it's O(2^n)? Can you show us some steps you followed to get that?

Comment: The same code was posted in CodeReview too, search. -- http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/49418/determining-if-an-answer-can-be-generated

Comment: The worst case appears to be non-terminating.

Comment: Thanks @MarcoAcierno that was the one I was looking for. -1

Comment: @MarcoAcierno Nobody there was able to solve it. They had *hours* long conversations, with varied answers. One said there can't be a complexity, other said it's O(2^n), so I figured maybe the folks here are experts.

Comment: The real question here is *what is n*?

Comment: Also, if a and b are allowed to be negative or zero, this will never terminate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that the variable n has no defined meaning in the context of this problem, so it makes no sense to express the runtime of your algorithm as a function of n.

Secondly, note that your algorithm only has reasonable terminating behavior if

- a and b are positive OR
- even for the initial a, b we have a + b > min{c, d}

The latter case is not particularly interesting, so let's concentrate on the former case. In particular we have a, b >= 1 in this case.

The pair (c, d) stays fixed during every recursion, so let's see what the nature of the pairs (a, b) is that your algorithm enumerates. Let A and B be the initial values of a and b. We have that in every function call, (a, b) = (x1 * A + y1 * B, x2 * A + y2 * B). The transitions are

```
((x1 + x2) * A + (y1 + y2) * B, x2 * A + y2 * B)
(x1 * A + y1 * B, (x1 + x2) * A + (y1 + y2) * B)
```

We can show that the function f(x1, y1, x2, y2) = (x1 + x2, y1 + y2) is injective when restricted to the values (x1, y1, x2, y2) that occur during the execution of the algorithm.

If we look at the complete recursion tree, without the prunings, f adopts the following values:

```
(1,1)
(1,2)
(1,3)
...
(2,1)
(2,3)
(2,5)
(2,7)
...
(3,1)
(3,2)
(3,4)
(3,5)
(3,7)
...
```

Notice the pattern? We can show that f adopts exactly the value pairs (x,y) with gcd(x,y) = 1 (the coprime pairs). Furthermore, because of the pruning, we only enumerate those pairs (x,y) with Ax + By <= min{c,d}. The runtime T of your algorithm, expressed as a function of A, B, c and d is thus

[image]

At this point I'm not sure how to establish the asymptotics of this function precisely. A quick-and-dirty upper bound that one gets after removing the co-primeness constraint and the floors, is T(A, B, c, d) = O(min{c,d}^2 / (A * B)) = O(min{c,d}^2). Not sure how tight this bound is.

**UPDATE:** In your CR post, you propose a much better algorithm to solve the problem. It still contains a bug, but it's a good start:

```
public static String betterSolution(int a, int b, int c, int d){
    while( c > a || d > b){
        if(c > d){
            if (d == 0) break; // otherwise, it does not terminate!
            c = c-d;
        }else{
            if (c == 0) break; // otherwise, it does not terminate!
            d = d-c;
        }
    }
    if( c == a &&  d == b){
        return "Able to generate";
    }else{
        return "Not able to generate";
    }
}
```

This algorithm is still only polynomial in the variables, O(max{c,d}) to be precise. You can improve it to logarithmic time by "skipping" over steps:

```
public static String evenBetterSolution(int a, int b, int c, int d){
    while( c > a || d > b){
        if(c > d){
            if (d == 0) break; 
            c = c - Math.max(1, (c - a) / d) * d;
        }else{
            if (c == 0) break;
            d = d - Math.max(1, (d - b) / c) * c;
        }
    }
    if( c == a &&  d == b){
        return "Able to generate";
    }else{
        return "Not able to generate";
    }
}
```

The algorithm is based on the [Euclidean GCD algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Using_Euclid.27s_algorithm) and the runtime is bounded by O(log(min{c,d})). Very good.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time out to educate me. I appreciate it. I fail to understand your evenBetterSolution, in particular, the Math.max(...)aspect of it; you seem to be doing something clever there. I like the witty method name as well.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say:

> a = -1 b = 0 c = 0 d = 0

These values will skip the first if, the second if and the third if and will go straight to

> ablehelper(a + b, b, c, d);

It turns out -1+0 is -1, and thus, we start over from the beginning and this has no end (but a stack overflow exception).
Regarding the complexity, it doesn't make much sense like Marco Acierno pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

This reminds me of the recent [TopCoder problem](http://community.topcoder.com/stat?c=problem_statement&pm=13142), so I will assume the missing piece of the statement comes from there. So, I'll answer the following question:

> Let *a*, *b*, *c* and *d* be integers from *1* to *n*, inclusive. What
>   is the time complexity of the coded algorithm with respect to *n*?

I'd say it's O(n^2). See how *c* and *d* remain constant, but *a* and *b* grow. If (the worst case) *a = b = 1* and *c = d = n*, we will visit each pair *(a, b)* where *a + b <= n* no more than once. To see why, consider a pair *(a, b)* and look back on how could it have been generated. It turns out that a pair *(a, b)* where *a > b* can be only generated by *(a - b, b)*, and if *a < b* it can be only generated by *(a, b - a)*. Otherwise, one of the values would have been negative, and since we start with positive *a* and *b*, they remain positive during the whole process.

More precisely, when we start with *a = b = 1*, we visit each pair *(a, b)* where the greatest common divisor of *a* and *b* is *1* exactly once, and don't visit any other pair. [The number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/422830/generating-all-coprime-pairs-within-limits) of such pairs is ~6n^2/PI^2 which is Θ(n^2).